# How to make a video like this with Blender software?

Tags: animation, node-editor, geometry

How to make a video like this with Blender software?

[image]

[Video link](https://nalej.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Blue-27239.mp4)

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a try:

[image]

You could subdivide a grid, then split each face:

[image]

Scale down each face with the *Transform Pivot Point* set to *Individual Origins*:

[image]

Choose the top view and unwrap with the *Project from View* option. Then in the *UV Editor* scale down again with the *Pivot* set to *Individual Origins*:

[image]

Create a mix between a *Transparent* and *Emission* shader with a *Noise Texture* as factor:

[image]

Animate the *Mapping* node on X and Z (you can also set the *Noise Texture* to *4D* and animate the *W* value to make the noise change while it moves on X):

[image]

Mix with some other noise textures if necessary, through a *Color > Mix Color* in *Darken* mode:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I think there are 2 noises passing in opposite directions in the reference? No biggie..

Comment: OK I'm going to edit  ;)

Comment: Ok friends. It is working. Thank you!